# How do I partition mongodb datasets?

Tags: database, mongodb, partitioning, sharding, database-partitioning

I'm stuck in mongodb sharding and I need your help!
My first question is "**How do I make my database partitioned:true in sh.status()?**
I've worked with sharding servers and mongos but I need to partition my documents base on datetime.So I used tags and zone-ranges but I couldn't make this option **true!**

[Here is the option I'm talking about:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiIh0.png)

I tried query it by sh.shardCollection("db.coll" , partitioned:true) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this 6.0? If so I don't think the `enableSharding` (eg step 2 in @R2D2's answer) is required anymore. The output of `partitioned` may not be meaningful in those versions

Comment: @user20042973 according documentation I would expect this flag always being `true` in MongoDB version 6.0

Comment: Which version of MongoDB do you use?

Comment: What version of what shell is getting used? Eg https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOSH-1152

Comment: I use version 6.0.4 .enableSharding still needed...

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the index on which you would like to  shard/partition:

   ```
   use <database>
   db.<collection>.createIndex({"<shard key field>":1})
   ```
2. Enable Sharding ( partition) the database:

   ```
   sh.enableSharding("<database>")
   ```
3. Shard the collection :

   ```
   sh.shardCollection("<database>.<collection>", { "<shard key field>" : 1, ... } )
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! The thing is I did all of these steps but the partitioned option doesn't turn to true...But sharding without a problem works!

Comment: this is strange indeed